# Excel 2013 Chart X-axis Date Labels

Tags: excel, charts

Is there a way to increment date labels by the start of every month in an excel chart?

i.e. Axis values should start in DD/MM/YY:
1/1/16, 1/2/16, 1/3/16....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of chart you use. In line and column charts, you can set the X axis to a date axis and let the major unit be 1 Month.

[image]

XY Scatter chart work differently. Here you will need to hide the X axis labels and use a data series to place the markers and add data labels, then format the series to no line and no markers. In the screenshot the series is still visible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the options were hidden to me precisely because it was a scatter plot

Answer (score 0):

Right click the dates on the x-axis and select "format axis".

Under "Axis Options" you can make the major unit 'fixed' at 1 month. It will then increment by the 1st of each month.
Setting a "minimum" date, will allow for setting the day which it starts (eg, if you wanted it to increment on the 3rd of each month, input 3-Jan-2016. I think the default is the first date in the data set.).

Make sure the category is set to "date" if excel doesn't recognise your date column. "format axis" -> "number" tab, or 'right click' -> 'format cells'.